# c# integer data load to text box by selecting dropdownlist

Tags: c#

i have tried to load the integer value to textbox from db by selecting the dropdownlist item. I didn't get any error, but the value was not display in the text box. this is the code what i have written, please correct me,

```
public void SiteNo()
    {
        Conhr.Open();
        //int anInteger;
        //anInteger = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
        //anInteger = int.Parse(TextBox1.Text);

        string sq = "select SiteCode from tbl_SiteMaster where  Sitealiasname='" + ddlsite.SelectedItem.Text + "' ";
        SqlCommand d = new SqlCommand(sq, Conhr);
        SqlDataReader r;
        r = d.ExecuteReader();
        while (r.Read())
        {
            TextBox1.Text = r.GetValue(0).ToString();
        }
        r.close();
        Conhr.Close();
    }
```

Comment: You might set a breakpoint on the line `TextBox1.Text = r.GetValue(0).ToString();` to make sure it is executed. Also when the breakpoint is hit, step over that line and observe the `TextBox1.Text` to see if has a value.

Comment: And please accept some answers on your previous questions.

Comment: are you sure this function has been exec????

Answer (score 0):

```
//change code to this to find the problem

public void SiteNo()
{
    Conhr.Open();
    //int anInteger;
    //anInteger = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
    //anInteger = int.Parse(TextBox1.Text);

    string sq = "select count(SiteCode) from tbl_SiteMaster where  Sitealiasname='" + ddlsite.SelectedItem.Text + "' ";
    SqlCommand d = new SqlCommand(sq, Conhr);
    SqlDataReader r;
    r = d.ExecuteReader();
    while (r.Read())
    {
        TextBox1.Text = r.GetValue(0).ToString();
    }
    r.close();
    Conhr.Close();
}
```

Comment: what is the error? i just change query of your code... if it doesnt exec please cpy/pst the error text!